# How to increase laser efficiency and decrease photon loss into the P and N layers?

Tags: semiconductor-physics, reflection, laser

So, I reading about lasers. We use mirrors to use the same photons to initiate the stimulated recombination. For this, we use mirrors.

Mirror (Very Highly reflective) | - Diode - | Mirror (Highly reflective)

Now, as per reading, the photons which do not obey the standing wave equation would die out. Now remaining would either get reflected by the mirrors or will be absorbed by the P or N layer above or below them. So I want to reduce this loss into P and N layers of the semiconductor layer, what approaches can we use?

Also, Can the lens be used for this situation?

Comment: Often the diode is set up to emit from the sides, with photons propagating through the depletion region only, not through bulk regions. Or, as in a VCSEL, the top layer is extremely thin so it has minimal absorption.

Comment: Yes, but as the light passes through the depletion region, the photons are lost at the boundary. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ta5M1LsAySw&list=PLyWzPf87clvEb8T3Xf30tMaUqdbVchrNY&index=36

Comment: There are losses inside the cavity, yes. So?